# Backup Sqlite objects in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, backup

I am about to implement backup for my Android app, and my issue is: The data resides in an sqlite db. Some of the data are just there for user convenience, and can be recreated from other sources. So in order to minimize the size, I wish to export relevant data only (the limit for backup using the Google API is 1mb).

All the data has class equivalents, which are populated via my SQLiteOpenHelper implementation. This means I can implement serialization.

So far I can see the following options:

- Serialization using Java Serializable, and write all objects into a binary chunk and pass it to writeEntityData()
- Serialization using XML or JSON, perhaps together with the zip API and dump the file as a binary chunk
- Clone the database with relevant objects only. Probably a lot of work.

So far, using XML or JSON seems to be the best option, as I can reuse that for data sharing across users/devices. Java Serializable seems to bloat the size..

Would like to hear your opinions on this !

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use vacuum() in order to shrink the db size, or use the [auto_vacuum pragma](http://sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_auto_vacuum).
If your db is something big, you can try to zip it.
Delete all unnecessary libs (compat_v7, for example, if you don't need it).
Try to compress images with [optipng](http://optipng.sourceforge.net/).
Try to convert your wav or mp3 to aac.

And... we are talking about how many Mb?

Comment: I can't see how deleting libs affects the database ? (and eventual unused libs would be stripped away from the release APK)

An initial database may be 7-800kb (at the moment), but will probably grow to perhaps 2mb. As for the user added data (that is being backed up), we may talk about 1-200 kb.

Vacuum would definitely be and option if I backed up the entire DB image, which I am not going to do.

Comment: No, I was talking about reducing your apk size.

Comment: Maybe you must think about changing your table / fields structure. Serialization will make grow your db, so... I think your db structure must be the most important point.  Can we see your database structure and relations?

Comment: APK size has nothing to do with this, and the structure of the database (which is as good as it can be) is not relevant... and serialization has absolutely nothing to do with the size of the database; serialization is about transporting/persisting objects. My question is about best practice for backing up selected sets of my data.